# Auto split table in multiple page

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I want the following table to automatically divide over multiple pages when it becomes too large for a page:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\hline
%@@@@@@@@@@@row@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}
&
\\
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]
{FFCC67}1}
&
MYTEXT
\\
\hline \hline
%######### END ROW #################

...............Lots of rows...............

%@@@@@@@@@@@row@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}
&
\\
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]
{FFCC67}1}
&
MYTEXT
\\
\hline \hline
%######### END ROW #################

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

The table is generated automatically so I can not handle it. It is also necessary that the table retain the same properties.

[image]

Comment: Possibly you should take a look at the package [tabu](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf). It provides an environment `longtabu` and it allows `X`-_columns_.

Comment: almost always a table set as `lx` is better set as a list (which then naturally breaks over a page) or you could use the `longtable` package.